# Cofibrantly generated categories, cardinals, and the Thomason model structure on $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

When reading up the general theory of cofibrantly generated model categories, anything related to the small object argument relies on the choice of some cardinal $\lambda$. I.e. we need $\lambda$-sequences to define $\lambda$-smallness, and a transfinite composition of a $\lambda$-sequence of pushouts of coprducts when applying the small object argument.

However, when Thomason uses the small object argument in order to prove that $\mathbf{Cat}$ (with generating cofibrations and generating trivial cofibrations as chosen) is indeed a cofibrantly generated model category, he doesn't even mention any cardinals and just talks about ordinary sequences.

My question is why. My guts tell me, that due to $\mathbf{Cat}$ being locally finitely presentable, he may chose $\lambda = \aleph_0$. I am however not familiar enough with the theory of locally finitely presentable categories to find a convincing argument why.

Moreover, does this imply that any $\lambda$-filtered colimit in $\mathbf{Cat}$ (or any other locally finitely presentable category) is in fact $\aleph_0$-filtered?

Comment: Unless you want to prove something about "small" objects, it is not actually necessary to know what $\lambda$ is – existence is good enough. There is a genuine distinction between $\lambda$-filtered colimits and $\aleph_0$-filtered colimits, however. (Exercise.)

Comment: If you go through the definition of $\lambda$-filtered categories, then it is easy to see that if $\kappa < \lambda$ then every $\lambda$-filtered category is a $\kappa$-filtered category